# Dynamically Allocate Memory without Malloc

Tags: c, memory-management, operating-system

I've been given a task to dynamically manage memory to beat the speed of malloc. Some requirements:

1) Have a pointer to a struct

2) Use "Chunks" of memory

3) The memory will be allocated with a call like

```
init(memory * mem, int chunk_size, int num_chunks)
```

4) The memory pointer will be declared globally.

5) Not using system calls

So, I've thought about having my struct simply just:

```
typdef struct {
  char *byte;
} memory;
```

And then that would leave my init function to do something like:

```
mem = new memory[chunk_size * num_chunks];
```

I don't know if you can do that in C -- normally I would use malloc! And then to free would I be able to just be able to set the pointer to null?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The `malloc` family of functions *is* the standard interface to dynamic memory allocation. You will use them (or some OS-specific equivalent) once to obtain a pool of memory and then use your allocator on that pool later on. Unless you have been specifically told not too call `malloc` to get the pool you are making this harder than it has to be.

Comment: Yes. The point is to make it harder than it needs to be. No systems calls--hopefully reducing overhead.

Comment: Do expect your allocator to be thread-safe?

Comment: For now, thread-safety is not an issue.

Comment: Set up a honking big array of `unsigned char` with static storage extent (i.e., declared at file scope or with the keyword `static`) as your "heap", then build some kind of data structure that indexes into it.

Comment: I would be tempted to guess that the malloc implementation is pretty sharp. So the only way to address your problem would be to first understand how malloc works and why. Then you can possibly code a "cheaper" malloc version that would be less sharp on some aspects that favors speed over whatever other principles that are required from malloc. It would most certainly mean that your version would not be iso C99 compliant and possibly less portable. In other words, why is it that malloc is too slow? It's about the fastest thing you can dream of in programming.

Comment: I would suggest you look into `jemalloc`, it consistently beats the `malloc (...)` that ships with MSVC's stdlib and glibc in user-mode and kernel-mode overhead. It performs roughly par with OS X's implementation of `malloc (...)`. I spent the better part of a year researching alternative memory allocators such as TCMalloc, Hoard, jemalloc, etc. in the context of real-time memory management and jemalloc had the lowest overhead in almost every usage pattern I tested. To be fair, virtually any allocator (other than Hoard) performs better than MSVC and glibc's default implementation.

Answer (score 6):

You can implement your own version of 'malloc' using system calls for process memory management...
Try brk, sbrk and mmap system calls to get memory from kernel...

This has a easy to understand implementation which you can implement and improve on

http://www.inf.udec.cl/~leo/Malloc_tutorial.pdf

Comment: These operations are expensive though and if you are implementing your own memory allocation scheme, you would need to take care of issues like  fragmentation of allocated memory

Comment: the provided link here is DEAD!

Comment: @ssp4all updated [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171014020821/http://www.inf.udec.cl/~leo/Malloc_tutorial.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

No, `new` is not supported in C, and setting a pointer to null does not free the associated memory. In fact that's a good way to leak memory.

It depends on the details of what you are trying to do, but typically you'd make some initial call to `malloc()` to get a largish block of memory, and then write your custom functions which you'd use to manage allocations from that large block within your program.

If you don't want to use `malloc()` at all, you'll have to use one of the memory allocation calls for your operating system. For example under Windows you might call `HeapAlloc()` or `GlobalAlloc()`. on UNIX systems you'd call `brk()` or `sbrk()`.

Comment: The problem with malloc's speed is the system calls. They have too much overhead.

Comment: You have to get the memory from the OS somehow, which requires a system call. I think what Charles is suggesting is that you make only a single system call ever, so the overhead is irrelevant.  Then you have your functions work within the block allocated by that single system call.

Comment: There is no way to get around making at least one system call to get the initial block of memory. There is no performance impact of a single call to malloc(), you just want to avoid making repeated calls. If your memory requirements are limited you might be able to use alloca() which allocates memory on the stack, but that's non-standard, and doesn't give much room (typically a few megabytes or less).